# Navigation issue in Xamarin Forms with same page type multiple time

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation

Relatively new to Xamarin, hitting an issue with PushAsync and navigation I can't figure out.

I have a main navigation page, and then a "MyContentPage" that is responsible for rendering a dynamic list based on a supplied id. When the user clicks on a list item they go to a next (newed up) "MyContentPage" (same class) with a different id. Basically a recursive page hierarchy based on a local db.

Problem is that navigation seems to quickly get messed up in some way I can't work out. The pages get swapped around, or get lost. Navigating back to root, if I click back down again, it skips to a page that is further down etc.

So basically the one page apart from the main page (which has multiple navigationpages in tabs - though I only use one tab at this point) binds its controls to this function:

```
public async Task NavigateToContent(int contentId)
    {

        await ((Application.Current.MainPage) as TabbedPage)?.CurrentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyContentPage(contentId));
    }
```

The above is then used recursively. Ie. Similar controls bind to the same function until there are no further pages to click down to.

The MyContentPage constructor loads the model:

```
 public MyContentPage(int id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _id = id;
        BindingContext = viewModel = new ContentPageViewModel(id);
    }
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: we can't debug code we can't see

Comment: @Jason Updated with code

Comment: why aren't you just doing Navigation.PushAsync()?

Comment: That NavigateToContent is being called from a 'service' , which itself is called from the base view model, using a ICommand bound to the controls in the dynamically generated list

Comment: Is it correct that Xamarin Forms has limitations when the same page type is re-used in navigation?

Comment: not that I'm aware of

Comment: @Sentinel don't put navigation code in the 'service' class. 'service' class should be something to call web api, etc. Leave the navigation source code to view model class.

Comment: @Sentinel I don't think there is limitation in xamarin forms for the same page type re-used in navigation.

Comment: @Sentinel Have a try with `public async Task NavigateToContent(int contentId)
    {

        await ((Application.Current.MainPage) as TabbedPage)?.CurrentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyContentPage{
                    BindingContext = new ContentPageViewModel(contentId)
                });
    }`You can refer to this sample to check where problem is.https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/GetStarted/Notes/MultiPage/

Comment: @JuniorJiang Thank you for your suggestion. Please can you shed some light on how that is different to my present code?

Comment: @Sentinel Does it work for you?

Comment: @JuniorJiang I am just about to try (early morning my time)… Give me a few minutes...

Comment: @JuniorJiang No, this makes no difference. The flow is exactly the same: the first button click seems to 'do nothing' (navigation does not change the page), a second click does change the page, but if I navigate back to root, when I click the button it takes me to the 3rd page.

Comment: @Sentinel Okey, could you show a video .Because I can't totally understand how navigation between views in your project. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191952/discussion-between-sentinel-and-junior-jiang-msft).

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT OK I tried to clarify in chat

Answer (score 0):

From what you mentioned in comments, the issue is caused by the navigation code called in the 'service' class. When you call the service method multiple times, it actually changes the current navigation stack in xamarin forms. Move the page navigation code from service class to viewmodel class.

Or try to put the page navigation source code into something like 'NavigationService' (one example is the one in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/ ) and inject this service into your view model class.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but my 'service' class is the Navigation Service class and approach. I believe I have that NavigationService as a single instance as an App property though

Answer (score 0):

OK so this all turned out to be an issue with concurrency.

The original button click was like this:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 


Task.Run(async () => await (BindingContext as ContentPageViewModel).ExecuteNavCommand(sender)); 
}
```

But this resulted in a UI operation happening on a different task

The event handler can be declared as async

The correction is

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await viewModel.ExecuteNavCommand(sender);

}
```